# Compiling boost::python with Python 3.4

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python, python-3.4

I am trying to compile boost::python with a local installation of Python 3.4.
I started by installing Python by downloading the source and running the following command:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local --disable-shared
make
make install
```

This installs Python in the `$HOME/local directory`. Since the Python interpreter is named `python3`, I created a link named `python` in `$HOME/local/bin` pointing to `python3`.

My PATH environment variable starts searching in `$HOME/local/bin` first, so now typing `python` gives me the interpreter I just installed.

I then tried to install Boost (1.57) with Python support through the following command:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=$HOME/local --with-python-root=$HOME/local --with-libraries=python
```

This command properly detects the Python installation (I see a "Detecting Python version... 3.4" in the output).

When running `./b2` to compile the libraries, however, I got a fatal error:

```
pyconfig.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

(in English: `pyconfig.h: no such file or directory`)

I went in `$HOME/local/include` where it's supposed to be and found out that while boost is trying to locate the include files in `$HOME/local/include/python3.4`, they are in fact located in `$HOME/local/include/python3.4m` (notice the "m" at the end). Similarly, the python library is named `libpython3.4m.a`.

I manage to have boost compile by creating a symbolic link python3.4 -> python3.4m in the include directory, and symbolic link libpython3.4.a -> libpython3.4m.a.

Now this is really not clean at all. My question is: why boost is not detecting the include files directly in python3.4m? Or why is Python installing its files in python3.4m instead of python3.4? Am I missing a step in configuring either one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16675865/645956

Comment: Thanks, this explains the "m" suffix, but not why Python didn't create the links himself.