# naming convention: What does the 'm' mean in libpython3.5m.dylib

Tags: python

I have python version 3.5 installed to a non-system directory.  The name of libpython is: `libpython3.5m.dylib`.  What does that last `m` character in the name mean?

Comment: It would be funny if it turns out to be `meters` right? Python 3.5 meters.

Comment: Very closely related to, though strictly speaking not a duplicate of, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675865/difference-between-python3-and-python3m-executables?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: Closely related also to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863827/what-is-libpython3-so-compared-with-libpython3-5m-so-built-from-python-3-5-2-sou.

Answer (score 12):

The suffix refers to an [ABI detail](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/#proposal) of the python library.  In this case, `m` indicates that `--with-pymalloc` was used when your python interpreter was compiled.  Other possible suffix characters include: `d` (`--with-pydebug`) and `u` (`--with-wide-unicode`).

More details on ABI tagging for extension modules can be found in [PEP 3149](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/).