# Trouble building caffe from source

Tags: c++, makefile, caffe, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install caffe by building it from [source](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe)

After issuing the following command from the caffe root directory

```
$ make all -j4
```

I am getting an error

```
...
CXX src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp
CXX src/caffe/blob.cpp
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lpython3.6
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:582: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

**Dependencies installed**

```
$ sudo apt install python3-opencv
$ sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libopencv-dev libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler
$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends libboost-all-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev
$ sudo apt-get install the python3-dev
```

**CUDA**: `CUDA 9` `CuDnn 7.4`

**Ubuntu**: `Ubuntu 18.04`

[Makefile.config](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yib5afza5zyytfx/Makefile.config?dl=0)

I have looked at all the [issues](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues) in the source Github repository but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved, I had to make the following changes in `Makefile.config` file

**From**

```
PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.6
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.6 \
/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
```

**To**

```
PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.6m
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.6m \
/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
```

Answer (score 1):

Therefore that your error states `cannot find -lpython3.6` you are missing the `libpython3.6.so` on your system.

Try to: 
`sudo apt-get install libpython3.6-dev`

Comment: try to `locate libpython3.6.so` and try to add that path to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before calling `make`

Comment: Or maybe the problem is, that in `libpython3.6-dev` there is a library called `libpython3.6m.so`. So either you try to link against `-lpython3` instead (which automatically uses `libpython3.6m.so` ... see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863827/what-is-libpython3-so-compared-with-libpython3-5m-so-built-from-python-3-5-2-sou)), or you try to create a symbolic link of `libpython3.6.so -> libpython3.6m.so`

Comment: I have found the issue, I have posted it as an answer.