# Cython standalone executable on ubuntu

Tags: linux, python-3.x, cython, executable

I want my cython program to be standalone executable on linux, not to be imported. After

> cython --embed

i got a c file,now how can i make it executable?

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you trying to make it `import`able in Python or are you trying to embed python and execute it? Please edit your question and elaborate on these to make it a bit easier for use to get what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard  i have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to compile the `.c` file you have obtained.

Assuming you are using python 3.5 and don't have to link to other libraries than python you can do this with a simple `gcc` command like :

```
gcc -I /usr/include/python3.5m -o your_program your_file.c -lpython3.5m
```

*(you might need to remove the `m` following the version number)*

As you expect it will use the `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement as entry-point of the program.

Comment: thanks, but could you explain me what is  (m) in lpython3.5m as i can successfully compile with 'm', and what would be effects if remove 'm'. Do i need to have "if__name=__main" as i have already compiled without it?

Comment: The `m` indicates that python was compiled with the support of `PyMalloc`, in a few words a more efficient allocator function than `malloc` system ones (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16677339/5050917 or https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/ for more details). The `if __name__ == "__main__":` isn't mandatory, you can also just let unindented the code you want to be executed when the program starts, exactly as when running it with python.

Comment: Use `ldconfig -p | grep python3.5` to see the libraries installed on your system. In my case i can see that I only have `libpython3.5m` to link against.

Comment: gcc -I /usr/include/python3.6 -o hello.c -lpython3.6m does not work for windows.

Comment: @HaydenDarcy Yes I have to admit it .. And I dont really have an answer for Windows right now. However the question was explicitly tagged "Linux".