# Create standalone compiled executable from Python script (uses sklearn)

Tags: python, linux, scikit-learn, cython, pyinstaller

Assume this is the code. It accepts a CSV file, does its thing, and gives some output. Called this way:

python test.py input.csv

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import sys

filename = sys.argv[-1]

val = np.genfromtxt(filename,delimiter=',')
target = val[:, 4]
features = val[:, [0,1,2,3]]

clf = SVC()
clf.fit(features, target)

print clf.predict([[6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8]])
```

Now I want to create a standalone executable which can run on any machine without any of the prerequisites installed (Python 2.7, numpy, sklearn, etc).

I used PyInstaller on Ubuntu 16.04 to create an executable:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs test.py
```

I can use the generated executable (size ~ 55 MB) on any Ubuntu machine without any prerequisites installed:

```
./test input.csv
```

It gives identical output.
So part of the problem is solved.
However the documentation: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/operating-mode.html#hiding-the-source-code

states that the source code cannot be protected and suggests Cython as a remedy. I came across this StackOverflow question [Cython standalone executable on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769516/cython-standalone-executable-on-ubuntu)

which delineates the usage of --embed option to include the Python interpreter. But how do I embed sklearn, numpy, etc with Cython to create a truly standalone application?

The execution should be simply:

```
./test input.csv
```

and the source code shouldn't be compromised. 
I need help with expanding on this [Cython standalone executable on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769516/cython-standalone-executable-on-ubuntu) question to embed external libraries (sklearn, numpy, etc) as well.

Comment: Is it vital for you to have the complete program in one script file or is it possible to split the script into a part that you want to hide and a simple python script calling that hidden code? To work with pyinstaller, we have to have some python entry point, whereas cython transpiles python code into c code pyinstaller can start nothing with. The compiled program will still be embedded into a single file you can call from command line.