# Get the `m` and others of `pythonX.Ym`

Tags: python

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675865/difference-between-python3-and-python3m-executables) for what the `m` means)

I need to construct the include path of `.virtualenvs/foo/include/pythonX.Ym` to compile something (i.e. `-I...`) against the virtualenv. I [can get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script) the `X.Y` using `sys.version` or `sys.final_version`.

How do I get the `m` to construct the include path?

EDIT: I tried `sys.executable` but that is pointing to `.../foo/bin/python`, which is unhelpful for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *easiest* way to get the include path is to use the [`sysconfig.get_path()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html#sysconfig.get_path):

```
import sysconfig

include_path = sysconfig.get_path('include')
```

This path is adjusted for virtualenvs already. For scripting purposes outside of Python, you can either print the path directly:

```sh
$ python -c 'import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path("include"))'
```

or get *all* `sysconfig` data by running the module as a script:

```
$ python -m sysconfig
```

then parse the output that dumps to stdout.

Other than that, if you only want the executable name (with the `m` included), you can get that from the [`sys.executable` variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable); this includes the `m` suffix:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python3.5m'
```

As of Python 3.2, you can also use the [`sys.abiflags` variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.abiflags); it is set to `m` in this case:

```
>>> sys.abiflags
'm'
```

Also see [PEP 3149](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/).

For earlier Python versions, the various flags that influence the suffixes are available still via the aforementioned `sysconfig` module as configuration variables:

```
pymalloc = bool(sysconfig.get_config_var('WITH_PYMALLOC'))
pydebug = bool(sysconfig.get_config_var('WITH_PYDEBUG'))
wideunicode = bool(sysconfig.get_config_var('WITH_WIDE_UNICODE'))
```

Note that ubuntu merely compiles multiple binaries and adjusts the executable name to reflect the configuration option chosen; on other systems the ABI flags are not necessarily reflected in the executable name.

Comment: Interesting. I am not getting the same as you when using a virtualenv (updated question)

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: I'll fire up a vm when I get at the office.

Comment: `sysconfig.get_path('include')` is definitely the answer to the question. :)

Comment: shouldn't it be [`sysconfig.get_config_var`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sysconfig.html#sysconfig.get_config_var) instead of `sysconfig.get_config`?