# What is the "m" behind python version like python3.6m

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently when I install python3.6 in Ubuntu 16.04 I see it installs both python3.6 and python3.6m

What the hell is **python3.6m**?
Should I use **python3.6** or **python3.6m** to run my python script?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The version ending with `m` is compiled with a very specialized version of the C function `malloc,` tailored to be faster in a python application.

For more info see: [Difference between python3 and python3m executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675865/difference-between-python3-and-python3m-executables/16677339)