# get different results when trying to find Python version in my mac

Tags: python

I run following to try to find the version of Python but get different results
[image]

Comment: can you tell me what do you mean by different result? I can see its giving correct version result. man page of which tells that  `which - shows the full path of (shell) commands.` so its showing full path of your current activated python interpreter

Comment: Your result is correct. `which` shows the path to the file, it does not follow symbolic links, so it won't show you to what exact version it links.

Comment: Strange question! You have more than one version of Python installed and you are defaulting to V.3.7.5.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: `ls -l $(which python)` - this will use the result path of `which` in `ls -l` that will show you the file info, including where the link goes (in your case line will end in `-> python3.7`)

Comment: I think I'm confused by the response of `python` - it shows so many pythons and I don't know what's they for?

Comment: `python<TAB><TAB>` shows programs that start with the name "python" anywhere on your path. The `2.7` programs are probably in /usr/bin. The `-config` programs say how that version was compiled. Use the `pythonw` program to run  things with built with Qt or wx. The `pythonm` programs are supposed to be faster (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16675865) for details), but your machine has `python3.7m => python3.7 => python3 => python` as file system links (similarly for 2.7). I don't know where `python.app` is coming from---maybe you installed as a standalone python from a .dmg file?